# Filtering and copying the filtered unique data to another sheet; sheet name would be the unique value

Tags: excel, vba

'I have a workbook with sheets containing data. I need the unique number to be filtered and copy the filtered data to another sheet, sheet name would be the unique number.

'i have tried to get all the numbers and remove duplicates, the remaining should be the filtered number to be copied.

'the error is i can copy the data to different sheets but not filtered according to their unique number

```
Sub filter()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ST As String
On Error Resume Next
i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do
ST = Sheets("duplicateshipto").Range("A" & i).Value
If ST <> "" Then
Sheets.Add.Name = ST
With Sheets("Template")
.Select
.Range("C1:BQ4").Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets(ST).Select
Sheets(ST).Range("A1").Select
Sheets(ST).Paste

.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BU$88").AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=gsd


.Range("Z4", .Range("BS" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Select

Range("Z4").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(ST).Select
Sheets(ST).Range("x5").Select
Sheets(ST).Paste
.Select
Range("BQ4").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(ST).Select
Sheets(ST).Range("BO6").Select
Sheets(ST).Paste
.Select
Range("Y4").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(ST).Select
Sheets(ST).Range("a5").Select
Sheets(ST).Paste

End With
i = i + 1
End If
Loop Until ST = ""

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description fully, but I think you are trying do something that you can solve with ten clicks and a pivot table. Read up on "Report Filter Pages"

Comment: Your description is unclear. In one place you write about data, in another you write about number or unique number or unique data.
What do you want to filter and what is the filtering based on exactly? What do you need to copy? How many sheets do you have? I would happily help but you should clarify your question first.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to do something called [Advanced Filter](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/16/advanced-filters-with-vba-to-automate-filtering-on-and-out-specific-values). However your code needs some improvement on all of the select options (as the comments state). Here's a sample macro that has several components you'll need for what you're trying to do such as:

- It dynamically captures the range of all to the populated cells to the left and down of cell `F6`.
- Uses the green range as what to filter (if not just leave F3:H3 blank)
- Inserts values starting in cell `A1` with a dynamic number of columns based on the number of data columns.
- Excludes duplicates using `Unique:=True` (only one duplicate in sample)

### Before Macro

[image: Before the Macro is Run]

### After Macro

[image: After Macro]

Code used in above illustration.

```
Sub exampleRefresh()
Dim cRng As Range, WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ActiveSheet

With WS
    Set cRng = Sheet1.Range("F6")
    Set cRng = Range(cRng, cRng.End(xlToRight))
    Set cRng = Range(cRng, cRng.End(xlDown))

    Dim fRng As Range
    Set fRng = WS.Range("F2:H3")

    Dim PRNG As Range
    Set PRNG = WS.Range("A1")
    Set PRNG = Range(PRNG, PRNG.Offset(, cRng.Columns.Count - 1))

End With


  cRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=fRng, CopyToRange:=PRNG, Unique:=True


End Sub
```

Also, as a teaser, Microsoft is going to be deploying a new [Spill Feature soon](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Preview-of-Dynamic-Arrays-in-Excel/ba-p/252944). With this functionality, if you wanted to list the distinct values of a column, you could use a formula such as `=Unique(A:A)` in any cell and it will create a distinct list. No VBA or excessive clicking needed!